# How to combine makefiles?

Tags: makefile

I encountered a software that had three makefiles, one in the root directory and two in immediate subdirectories. Experimenting a bit it turned out that there is a good order of them:

```
$ make -C wordn all
$ make -C buses all
$ make all
```

from the root directory. What is an elegant way to rewrite the main makefile so that this sequence happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the target `all` of the main `Makefile` you can add:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) -C wordn all
    $(MAKE) -C buses all
    ...
```

This will execute the submake before doing the `all` commands.

You can also create a dependency of the main `all` target:

```
all: suball
    ...

suball:
    $(MAKE) -C wordn all
    $(MAKE) -C buses all

.PHONY: suball
```

*The `suball` target must be a [`PHONY`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) target as it is a virtual target*